# ajax post request controller handling

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, post

I'm trying to get a simple ajax post request working, so that when I click a button on my html page, a javascript event listener is called, which makes an ajax post request, which returns some text. I'm trying to get it to work so that the success function in my ajax request prints out the received text, but am having trouble completing this and think it's because of how my controller.rb file is handling the request. So far I have:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

<h1>Welcome to my website#index</h1>

<input class="className" id="idName" type="button" value="Click Me!" id="my_button" remote:true/>

<ul id="ulID">
 <div class = 'wantToChange'>This should change when button is pressd.</div>
</ul>
```

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.className').on('click', function(){
        console.log("inside js click listener");

       $.post('superman', { field1: "hello", field2 : "hello2"}, 
       function(returnedData){
            console.log(returnedData);
       });

    });
});
```

**welcome_controller.rb**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def superman
    some_parameter = params[:some_parameter]
    #do something with some_parameter and return the results
    render plain: "OK"
  end

end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :test do
    collection do
      get 'test'
    end
  end

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

But running this just produces the following error when I click on the button:
    POST http://localhost:3000/superman 404 (Not Found)
Which makes me think my controller file is not set up correctly to receive this 'superman' route? Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi @martin, I can't see the ajax request to be fired on on click button instead it's been fired on `$(document).ready(function(){......})` ?

Comment: sorry my question was missing that code, i fixed it. I know the js function works because whenever i click the button i get "inside js click listener" in console

Comment: `remote:true` should be `data-remote = "true"`. I don't think this is the crutch of the issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1=> Index.html.erb

```
<!-- this line should be in application.html.erb 
  <%#= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
-->
<h1>Welcome to my website#index</h1>

<input class="className" id="button_to_be_clicked" type="button" value="Click Me!" id="my_button"/>

<ul id="ulID">
 <div class = 'want_to_change'>This should change when button is pressd.</div>
</ul>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#button_to_be_clicked').on('click', function(){
      // ajax request 
       $.ajax({
         url: "/superman",
         type: "POST",
         data : {
           value1: "hello",
           value2: "hello2"            
         },
         dataType: "script",
      });        
     })
   </script>
```

2 => routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'

  post '/superman', to: 'welcome#superman'

  resources :test do
    collection do
      get 'test'
    end
  end
end
```

3 => welcome_controller.rb

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def superman
    value1 = params[:value1]
    value1 = params[:value2]
    render plain: "OK"
  end

end
```

3 => superman.js.erb

```
$('.want_to_change').html("Text to be changed on ajax request.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform ajax request by using the gem **remotipart**
You simple need to add the gem

```
gem 'remotipart', github: 'mshibuya/remotipart', ref: '88d9a7'
```

Then you need to do some simple changes in the form

```
<%= form_for @document, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "create-document-form" }, :remote => true do |document_form| %>
  <%= document_form.file_field :file_upload, class: "custom-file-input" %>
<% end %>
```

For example i am using the above form for posting the new document throgh ajax
So in the controller It will directly come

```
def create
  @document = Document.new(document_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @document.save
      data = {visible_for_client: @document.visible_for_client, file_name: file_name.to_json, description: @document.description, file_path: file_url}.to_json
      format.js { render :js => "append_document(#{data});" }
    else
      format.json { render json: { errors: @document.errors.full_messages }, status: 422 }
    end
  end
end
```

So i wil call the js method from the controller and pass my message data and message throgh that method.

```
function append_document(data){
  console.log("Document created successfully.")
}
```